# What is the difference between using the iphonesimulator sdk and the macosx sdk in the Swift REPL?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, swift, read-eval-print-loop

You can run the Swift REPL with a couple of different options for the `--sdk` option. You can run:

```
xcrun swift -v -sdk $(xcrun --show-sdk-path --sdk iphonesimulator)
```

or

```
xcrun swift -v -sdk $(xcrun --show-sdk-path --sdk macosx)
```

There is also

```
xcrun swift -v -sdk $(xcrun --show-sdk-path --sdk iphoneos)
```

Which doesn't seem to work very well and causes lots of errors. 
How will my output differ when using the iphonesimulator sdk vs the macosx sdk?

Answer (score 4):

The desktop, device emulator and device hardware are different build targets:

```
SDK               Target
macosx            OSX Desktop
iphonesimulator   iOS Simulator
iphoneos          iOS Hardware
```

> Currently, xcodebuild supports these platforms:

```
 OS X           The local Mac, referred to in the Xcode interface as My Mac, and which supports the fol-lowing following
                lowing keys:

                arch  The architecture to use, either x86_64 (the default) or i386.

 iOS            An iOS device, which supports the following keys:

                name  The name of the device to use.

                id    The identifier of the device to use, as shown in the Devices tab of the Xcode
                      Organizer.

 iOS Simulator  The iOS Simulator, which supports the following keys:

                name  The full name of device to simulate, as presented in Xcode's UI.

                OS    The version of iOS to simulate, such as 6._, or the string latest (the default) to
                      indicate the most recent version of iOS supported by this version of Xcode.
```

This is abstracted in the IDE:

> For iOS, Xcode automatically switches between the iOS Simulator SDK and the device SDK, depending on where you intend to run your app. You don’t need to select these settings manually.

**References**

- [Xcodebuild Command Line FAQ](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2339/_index.html)
- [Mac OSX Glossary](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/SLGlobalGlossary/Glossary/Glossary.html)
- [XCode Release Notes Archive](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/RN-Xcode-Archive/Chapters/Introduction.html)
- [Configuring a Project for SDK-Based Development](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Configuring/configuring.html)